# wcf data service format the response as xml

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have created a wcf data service like this

```
public class Northwind : DataService< SelfServiceEntities >
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("SMS", EntitySetRights.AllRead
                | EntitySetRights.WriteMerge
                | EntitySetRights.WriteReplace);
        }
    }
```

and when I request this url

```
http://localhost:2242/Northwind.svc/SMS
```

I got this response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="http://localhost:2242/Northwind.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><id>http://localhost:2242/Northwind.svc/SMS</id><title type="text">SMS</title><updated>2014-02-05T08:33:49Z</updated><link rel="self" title="SMS" href="SMS" /><entry><id>http://localhost:2242/Northwind.svc/SMS(1)</id><category term="SelfServiceModel.SM" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" title="SM" href="SMS(1)" /><title /><updated>2014-02-05T08:33:49Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ID><d:number>1</d:number><d:body_ar>1</d:body_ar><d:body_en>1</d:body_en></m:properties></content></entry><entry><id>http://localhost:2242/Northwind.svc/SMS(2)</id><category term="SelfServiceModel.SM" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" title="SM" href="SMS(2)" /><title /><updated>2014-02-05T08:33:49Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:ID><d:number>55</d:number><d:body_ar>55</d:body_ar><d:body_en>55</d:body_en></m:properties></content></entry></feed>
```

#### my question

How can I make the response formatted as xml?

I made a research and I found this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668794%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
that states

```
OData builds on standard Internet protocols to make data services interoperable with applications that do not use the .NET Framework. Because you can use standard URIs to address data, your application can access and change data by using the semantics of representational state transfer (REST), specifically the standard HTTP verbs of GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE. This enables you to access these services from any client that can parse and access data that is transmitted over standard HTTP protocols.
```

> OData defines a set of extensions to the Atom Publishing Protocol (AtomPub). It supports HTTP requests and responses in more than one data format to accommodate various client applications and platforms. An OData feed can represent data in Atom, JavaScript Object Notation (JSON), and as plain XML. **While Atom is the default format, the format of the feed is specified in the header of the HTTP request**. For more information, see OData: Atom Format and OData: JSON Format.

Comment: That looks like xml to me?

Comment: @StuartLC the browser didn't read it as xml. when i was working with REST on java. i can produce the response that can be read by browser as xml. i mean nodes and collabse . u got me?